# Firebase Cloud Messaging issues / changes with iOS 10.3

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that I am building and prior to 10.3, the push notifications worked perfectly.

When 10.3 was released the whole Firebase tool set seemed to break for a couple of weeks until Google updated the PODs for the Framework.

Once done, I started again to play with this, but even though the previous code to push notifications worked to the previous build of the app the version built with 10.3 doesn't see any messages.

If I user NWPusher to push messages using the APN direct then I get messages fine, but the ones that were and still are working to the older version of the app don't get seen in the app / on screen / or in the debug window when connected to XCODE.

Has anyone had similar issues?

The code is unchanged from the version that previously worked and the direct push via APN works as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing something fishy happening with my notifications not beign delivered to a 10.3.1 device. All other devices are getting the notifications. I am sending via *topic subscriptions* ... hope they fix it soon